# PHP: How to append an array inside an array that already has an array value present

Tags: php, arrays

I am having the Following code:

```
$counter = $total_amt = 0;
$data = "";

$address = array(
                    'name'       => filter_var($_POST["cust_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                    'contact'    => filter_var($_POST["cust_contact"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
                    'pincode_id' => filter_var($_POST["cust_pincode"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
                    'address'    => filter_var($_POST["cust_address"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                    'landmark'   => filter_var($_POST["cust_landmark"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                    'state_id'   => filter_var($_POST["cust_state"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                    'city_id'    => filter_var($_POST["cust_city"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
                );

foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item)
    {
        if($counter < 1)
            {
                $data = array(
                                'item'     => $item['id'],
                                'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
                                'price'    => $item["price"]
                             );
            }
        elseif($counter >= 1)
            {
                $data = array(
                                'item'     => $item['id'],
                                'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
                                'price'    => $item["price"]
                             );
                $data[] = $data;
            }

        $total_amt = $total_amt + $item["final_price"];
        $counter ++;
    }
```

I am getting following output of the code:

```
Array
  (
    [item] => 3
    [quantity] => 1
    [price] => 810
      [0] => Array
        (
           [item] => 3
           [quantity] => 1
           [price] => 810
        )

 )
```

I am expecting this kind of O/P

```
Array
  (
      [0] => Array
        (
           [item] => 2
           [quantity] => 2
           [price] => 670
        )
      [1] => Array
        (
           [item] => 3
           [quantity] => 1
           [price] => 810
        )

 )
```

What's happening is i have two products added in cart using php sessions. I want to add that session variable to and array and then store it in database using serialize function. But, i am not able to store the variables in array format as shown above.

I have even tried the array_merge() function and othe logics but none is giving me this output. Can anyone help me out with this logic. Thanks in advance _/_

Comment: Don't use the same variable name `$data` for both arrays.

Comment: so then how should I append it? I mean to say where is my logic failing and at what point should I implement the new variable so that even if there are more than 2 arrays they can be added easily.

Comment: It's all explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your script like this. You also get rid of useless code.

```
$data = array();
...

foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item)
    {

         $data[] = array(
             'item'     => $item['id'],
             'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
             'price'    => $item["price"]
         );
        $total_amt = $total_amt + $item["final_price"];
    }
```

Comment: `new Array()` in PHP?

Comment: one more question @Dez what i want is i have created an array like this `$data[$item['id']] = array()` which means it will create an array value with name whatever the value is in `$item['id']`, What i want to do is i want to create a last array with name total to store the total amount in it. how to achieve so ?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Anyway, you should create a new question independently with your new found doubts.

Comment: Oh, I think I got what you meant. After the loop, you can add a new element to the array. For example in your case: `$data['total'] = array( 'price' => $total_amt);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're reusing the variable `$data`.

When you do

```
$data = array(
                'item'     => $item['id'],
                'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
                'price'    => $item["price"]
             );
```

it throws array the old `$data` array, and replaces it with this array.

Then you do:

```
$data[] = $data;
```

and it adds a copy of this array to itself.

You can simply write:

```
$data[] = array(
                'item'     => $item['id'],
                'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
                'price'    => $item["price"]
             );
```

to add a new element to `$data` containing this array.

There's also no need for the test `if ($counter == 1)` to do something different for the first entry. You should just initialize `$data` to be an empty array before the loop.

```
$data = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change this to:**

```
if($counter < 1)
{
      $data = array(
           'item'     => $item['id'],
           'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
           'price'    => $item["price"]
      );
}
elseif($counter >= 1)
{
     $data = array(
            'item'     => $item['id'],
            'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
            'price'    => $item["price"]
                  );
     $data[] = $data;
}
```

**This:**

```
if ($counter < 1)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'item' => $item['id'],
        'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
        'price' => $item["price"]
    );
}
elseif ($counter >= 1)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'item' => $item['id'],
        'quantity' => $item["quantity"],
        'price' => $item["price"]
    );
}
```